# Customized Global Search functionality using Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2016 Online?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

Microsoft Dynamic CRM Online provide in built functionality of Global CRM Search functionality: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KujytK3E4nI

I have design a HTML page and add as a WebResource in Solution. In that form I have a Search Textbox and search button. I want to provide customize functionality of Global Search in this HTML page.

Can anybody suggest me Query of Global CRM Search using Ajax Call?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can reuse OOB Global Search capabilities. What you can do is to check solution developed by Scott Durow - https://github.com/scottdurow/SparkleXrm/tree/master/SparkleXrmSamples/MultiEntitySearch